# Workaround for 'Navigation is blocked' error on Chrome Android when trying to use window.open on page load - ReactJS

Tags: android, reactjs, google-chrome

I am trying to trigger the sms/email/phone apps on page load. However, it doesn't work on page load in Chrome on Android, throwing the error 'navigation is blocked'. Is there a workaround for this issue on React?

I see some answers referring to using a post, redirect, get method, but I'm not sure how to implement that for React (if that is even possible).